# Why mouse hover in Selenium Web driver does not work with FF 11 and FF 17 but works with FF 14.0.1?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mousehover

For Windows 7,on a web application, I need to do Mouse hover on one link and then click on the link present in the submenu. I observed that below piece of code is working on FF 14, IE 8 and Google Chrome 23.0 [For chrome,only if I physically keep mouse pointer out of the browser screen.]  I used 2.25 jars for this.
I wanted to run it on FF 17. I tried running it by using 2.28 jars as well. But it did not work. I tried using Java script executor as well, but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated to understand why it is version specific. ?

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
    driver.get(MyURL);    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Path for object1
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu']/li[4]/a/span"));
    // Path for object2  
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu']/div[2]/a"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  
    ele1.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Which OS?, Which Selenium version? Is it a CSS :Hover?